# How to check the windows path matches with partial Linux path string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to check what files that are present in my `full_list_files` are also present in `required_list`.
The thing here is they are not exactly equal to one other , but macthes with filename and last sub directory.

Example :
`'C:\Users\Documents\Updated\Build\Output\M\Application_1.bin'` matches with `"M/Application_1.bin"` except the slashes are different.
So I am trying to make both uniform by using the function `convert_fslash_2_bslash`

But still, I see the output as below ,none of the files are matched.

```
full_list_files =  set(['C:\\Users\\Documents\\Updated\\Build\\Output\\O\\Report.tar.gz', 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Updated\\Build\\Output\\N\\Application_2.bin', 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Updated\\Build\\Output\\O\\Testing.txt', 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Updated\\Build\\Output\\M\\masking.tar.gz', 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Updated\\Build\\Output\\N\\Application_1.bin', 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Updated\\Build\\Output\\M\\Application_1.bin', 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Updated\\Build\\Output\\O\\History.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Updated\\Build\\Output\\O\\Challenge.tar.gz', 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Updated\\Build\\Output\\M\\Application_2.bin', 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Updated\\Build\\Output\\N\\porting.tar.gz', 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Updated\\Build\\Output\\M\\Booting.tar.gz'])

original required_list =  set(['N/Application_2.bin', 'M/masking.tar.gz', 'N/Application_1.bin', 'O/Challenge.tar.gz', 'M/Application_1.bin', 'O/Testing.txt', 'M/rooting.tar.gz', 'M/Application_2.bin', 'O/History.zip', 'N/porting.tar.gz', 'O/Report.tar.gz'])

modified required_list =  ['N\\Application_2.bin', 'M\\masking.tar.gz', 'N\\Application_1.bin', 'O\\Challenge.tar.gz', 'M\\Application_1.bin', 'O\\Testing.txt', 'M\\rooting.tar.gz', 'M\\Application_2.bin', 'O\\History.zip', 'N\\porting.tar.gz', 'O\\Report.tar.gz']

'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Updated\\Build\\Output\\O\\Report.tar.gz'  not present
'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Updated\\Build\\Output\\N\\Application_2.bin'  not present
'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Updated\\Build\\Output\\O\\Testing.txt'  not present
'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Updated\\Build\\Output\\M\\masking.tar.gz'  not present
'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Updated\\Build\\Output\\N\\Application_1.bin'  not present
'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Updated\\Build\\Output\\M\\Application_1.bin'  not present
'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Updated\\Build\\Output\\O\\History.zip'  not present
'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Updated\\Build\\Output\\O\\Challenge.tar.gz'  not present
'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Updated\\Build\\Output\\M\\Application_2.bin'  not present
'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Updated\\Build\\Output\\N\\porting.tar.gz'  not present
'C:\\Users\\Documents\\Updated\\Build\\Output\\M\\Booting.tar.gz'  not present
```

How can I get it working correctly.

```
import os
import sys
import re

full_list_files = {
    #These are actually real paths parsed from listdir
    #Just for convenience used as strings
    'C:\Users\Documents\Updated\Build\Output\M\Application_1.bin',
    'C:\Users\Documents\Updated\Build\Output\M\Application_2.bin',
    'C:\Users\Documents\Updated\Build\Output\M\masking.tar.gz',
    'C:\Users\Documents\Updated\Build\Output\M\Booting.tar.gz',
    'C:\Users\Documents\Updated\Build\Output\N\Application_1.bin',
    'C:\Users\Documents\Updated\Build\Output\N\Application_2.bin',
    'C:\Users\Documents\Updated\Build\Output\N\porting.tar.gz',
    'C:\Users\Documents\Updated\Build\Output\O\Challenge.tar.gz',
    'C:\Users\Documents\Updated\Build\Output\O\History.zip',
    'C:\Users\Documents\Updated\Build\Output\O\Testing.txt',
    'C:\Users\Documents\Updated\Build\Output\O\Report.tar.gz'
}

required_list = {
    "M/Application_1.bin",
    "M/Application_2.bin",
    "M/masking.tar.gz",
    "M/rooting.tar.gz",
    "N/Application_1.bin",
    "N/Application_2.bin",
    "N/porting.tar.gz",
    "O/Challenge.tar.gz",
    "O/History.zip",
    "O/Testing.txt",
    "O/Report.tar.gz"
}

def convert_fslash_2_bslash(required_file_list):
    required_config_file_list = []
    i = 0
    for entry in required_file_list:
        entry = entry.strip()
        entry = entry.replace('"',"")
        entry = entry.replace('/','\\')
        required_config_file_list.insert(i, entry)
        i = i + 1
    return required_config_file_list

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print

    print "full_list_files = ", full_list_files

    print

    print "original required_list = ", required_list

    print

    required_config_file_list = convert_fslash_2_bslash(required_list)

    print "modified required_list = ", required_config_file_list

    print

    for f_entry in full_list_files:
        f_entry = repr(f_entry)
        #for r_entry in required_config_file_list:
        #if ( f_entry.find(r_entry) != -1):
        if f_entry in required_config_file_list:
            print f_entry ," present"
        else:
            print f_entry ," not present"
```

Comment: this is the full program, i tried checking `if f_entry in required_config_file_list:` but it seems not the correct way, not a regular user of python

Comment: Is there a reason that you're using Python 2.7? Is there anything preventing you from using Python 3? 2.7 is well past its official end-of-life support, and users are **strongly** encouraged to upgrade.

Comment: Its an oldest tool we are working on needs some modifications, cannot change version now, not in my hands anyway

Comment: @snakecharmerb `os.path.split()` only returns the last component (`tail`, the filename) and the rest of the path (`head`). OP needs the last directory plus the filename.

Comment: yes @MattDMo is right, just tried the modification we get duplicates with `os.path.split`. The same filename may be present in two different sub directories

Comment: @snakecharmerb, but looks like i am messing with slashes i think.  sample: `("Head of ''C:\\\\Users\\\\Documents\\\\Updated\\\\Build\\\\Output\\\\O\\\\Report.tar.gz':'", "'C:\\\\Users\\\\Documents\\\\Updated\\\\Build\\\\Output\\\\O")
("Tail of ''C:\\\\Users\\\\Documents\\\\Updated\\\\Build\\\\Output\\\\O\\\\Report.tar.gz':'", "Report.tar.gz'", '\n')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the logic you need at the bottom:

```
for f_entry in full_list_files:
    for r_entry in required_config_file_list:
        if f_entry.endswith(r_entry):
            print f_entry, " present"
```

You need to loop over *both* collections, then check to see if the longer path ends with the shorter path. One of your mistakes was calling `repr()`, which changes the double backslashes to quadruple ones.

I'll leave it up to you to decide how you'll handle printing paths that are not present at all.

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo, infact i used this (endswith) before, but could not think in hurry